# Do I need to insulate the case of an electrolytic capacitor from ground?

Tags: capacitor, inverter, motor-controller, electrolytic-capacitor

I'm designing a motor controller, and I'm trying to understand if I need to add insulation between the case of the bulk input capacitors and the grounded aluminum heatsink. I know that relying on the PVC marking sleeve on the capacitor is a bad idea, if insulation is necessary. I also know that allowing anything besides the ground potential to contact the case won't work, but I'm unclear about this particular scenario.

I've found many references that say the case may be connected to the cathode, but with a heatsink also connected to the same ground as the cathodes that doesn't seem like a problem. I've also found references from several manufacturers saying the case always needs to be insulated, with no mention of whether the case is connected to the anode or the cathode.

I haven't picked a specific capacitor yet because I need to figure out how it fits mechanically first, but I'm looking for something similar to Chemi-Con [EKZN800ELL471MK30S](https://www.chemi-con.co.jp/products/relatedfiles/capacitor/catalog/KZNLL-e.PDF) if it makes a difference.

Comment: I've never heard of any concerns. Why is the heatsink contacting the capacitor anyways?

Comment: Electrolytic capacitors shouldn't be in contact with parts that get hot like heatsinks anyway; they degrade or in particularly bad cases can explode from heat.

Comment: I've found that AL electrolytic capacitors the case has ohmic contact (not a direct short) with the innards. It has bitten me once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to connect metal body capacitors with a metal heatsink?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/603943/is-it-safe-to-connect-metal-body-capacitors-with-a-metal-heatsink). My answer has multiple sources for manufacturer appnotes saying you need to insulate the can. Can may not be anode or cathode of the cap.

Comment: @Justme your answer actually has two conflicting sources for my scenario. Number 2 says "The case may be connected to the same potential as the negative terminal", while number 3 says "Completely isolate teach of the followings: case".

Comment: @DKNguyen the heatsink is part of the case, which also acts as an EMI shield.

Comment: @BrianSilverman Each manufacturer makes different capacitors and each series of capacitors may be different, hence different instructions. If you do something that is allowed by some capacitors, some other capacitors may simply short or blow up or whatever. If you want to be sure, do what is safe for all caps.